# Rails client side validations customize a pass message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, client-side-validation

I have implemented Rails gem **client_side_validations** which works great. Though I would like to add a pass message after each field value passes validation and I can't figure out if this is native to the gem.

Actuallly what I would like to do is add a "tick" symbol.

Is it possible to customize it this way easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a callback to achieve this: `ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass(element, callback, eventData)`

From the [Callbacks section](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#callbacks) in the documentation:

```
All form callbacks will receive the form in a jQuery object as the first 
parameter and the eventData object as the second parameter.
```

Comment: thank you. This looks like what I need to give the effect I want